# sorting json data in javascript with 2 dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, date, lodash

I have the following json data:

```
data = [
  {
    stateCode: 'CH',
    startDate: new Date('06/12/2020 08:00'),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date('06/12/2020 08:00'),
  },
  {
    stateCode: 'LA',
    startDate: new Date('06/12/2020 08:00'),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date('06/12/2020 08:30'),
  },
  {
    stateCode: 'NY',
    startDate: new Date('06/12/2020 06:00'),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date('06/12/2020 06:00')
  }
]
```

The data should be sorted by startDate by default. But if the startDate for 2 records is same then it should be sorted by stateDateWithDelay property. In the above example, startDate for first 2 records is same. So, in that case it should be sorted based on startDateWithDelay property.

After sorting the result should display the following states based on the 2 dates:

New York NY
Chicago CH
Los Angeles LA

I am using the following code to sort based on the startDate

```
import { sortBy } from 'lodash-es'
data = data.sortBy(data, (obj) => obj.startDate);
```

How do the accomplish sorting by the startDateWithDelay property when startDate is same for first 2 records.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can sort based on two parameters using a custom sort function passed to `Array.prototype.sort`

```js
const data = [
  {
    stateCode: 'CH',
    startDate: new Date('06/12/2020 08:00'),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date('06/12/2020 08:00'),
  },
  {
    stateCode: 'LA',
    startDate: new Date('06/12/2020 08:00'),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date('06/12/2020 08:30'),
  },
  {
    stateCode: 'NY',
    startDate: new Date('06/12/2020 06:00'),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date('06/12/2020 06:00')
  }
]

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
  const startDateComparison = a.startDate - b.startDate
  if (startDateComparison !== 0) return startDateComparison
  return a.startDateWithDelay - b.startDateWithDelay
})

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: can we not make use of lodash ? this logic is inside my react application.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
data = [
  {
    stateCode: 'CH',
    startDate: new Date('06/12/2020 08:00'),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date('06/12/2020 08:00'),
  },
  {
    stateCode: 'LA',
    startDate: new Date('06/12/2020 08:00'),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date('06/12/2020 08:30'),
  },
  {
    stateCode: 'NY',
    startDate: new Date('06/12/2020 06:00'),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date('06/12/2020 06:00')
  }
];

data.sort((a,b)=>{
 if(a.startDate.getTime() < b.startDate.getTime()){
  return -1
 }else if(a.startDate.getTime() < b.startDate.getTime()){
  return 1
 }else{
  return a.startDateWithDelay.getTime() - b.startDateWithDelay.getTime()
 }
});

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Or `data.sort((a, b) => (a.startDate - b.startDate) || (a.startWithDelay - b.startWithDelay))`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use `Array.prototype.sort` as, `Array.prototype.sort` function gives us the **flexibility to override the sorting behavior of an array** for any type of array data, and can be used for custom sorting orders over custom properties. Look at the last example that I have given.

```
const data = [
  {
    stateCode: "CH",
    startDate: new Date("06/12/2020 08:00"),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date("06/12/2020 08:00"),
  },
  {
    stateCode: "LA",
    startDate: new Date("06/12/2020 08:00"),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date("06/12/2020 08:30"),
  },
  {
    stateCode: "NY",
    startDate: new Date("06/12/2020 06:00"),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date("06/12/2020 06:00"),
  },
];

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
  // one liner using conditional operator
  return a.startDate - b.startDate === 0
    ? a.startDateWithDelay - b.startDateWithDelay
    : a.startDate - b.startDate;
});

console.log(sorted);
```

In the same example if we had to sort over states in the order of 'LA', 'NY' & 'CH' then we could have done this too as shown in the below example.

```
const data = [
  {
    stateCode: "CH",
    startDate: new Date("06/12/2020 08:00"),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date("06/12/2020 08:00"),
  },
  {
    stateCode: "LA",
    startDate: new Date("06/12/2020 08:00"),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date("06/12/2020 08:30"),
  },
  {
    stateCode: "NY",
    startDate: new Date("06/12/2020 06:00"),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date("06/12/2020 06:00"),
  },
];

// Custom Sorting based on States in order of 'LA', 'NY' & 'CH'
const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
  const sCa = a.stateCode; //state code of a
  const sCb = b.stateCode; //state code of b
  return (sCa === 'LA' && sCb !== 'LA') || (sCa === 'NY' && sCb === 'CH') ? -1 : 
  (sCb === 'LA' && sCa !== 'LA') || (sCb === 'NY' && sCa === 'CH') ? 1 : 0;
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: The last hard–coded sort would be much better using [*localeComare*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), e.g. `(a, b) => a.stateCode.localeCompare(b.stateCode)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [
  {
    stateCode: 'CH',
    startDate: new Date('06/12/2020 08:00'),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date('06/12/2020 08:00'),
  },
  {
    stateCode: 'LA',
    startDate: new Date('06/12/2020 08:00'),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date('06/12/2020 08:30'),
  },
  {
    stateCode: 'NY',
    startDate: new Date('06/12/2020 06:00'),
    startDateWithDelay: new Date('06/12/2020 06:00')
  }
]
```

We can use the inbuilt sort function of the arrays, so we will compare the startDate if they are the same, we will sort on startDateWithDelay else continue sorting on startDate.

```
let data2 = data.sort((s1, s2) => s1.startDate == s2.startDate ? 
            s1.startDateWithDelay - s2.startDateWithDelay : 
            s1.startDate - s2.startDate);
```

Once the sorting is done, we can use map to modify the result and join the sorted list of states for expected output.

```
let states = data2.map(s => s.stateCode).join(', ');
```

This will output the expected result.

```
NY, CH, LA
```